# Javascript - Disable Key Down selectively

Tags: javascript, keydown

My application has a image palette.  I am using key board shortcuts to move next and previous images.  The following is the code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 65) {
    beforeAfterImages(1);
    gtfval();
  }

  if(e.which == 39 || e.which == 68) {
    beforeAfterImages(2);
    gtfval();
  }

})
```

In the same page, I have a button, that opens a modal window.  The modal window has fields for text input.  During text input When I press a or d the image palette behind the modal keeps moving.  Can I disable the keydown functions, when I open the modal window.  I tried the following:

```
$('#myModal').click(function() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 65) {
    return false;
  }

  if(e.which == 39 || e.which == 68) {
    return false;
  }

})
});
```

Comment: You can either check if the modal is open every time, or [remove the event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) when the modal is open, then re-create it again when it's closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the modal, you can edit a variable, like `var isModalOpen`. Then check that everytime the user presses the keys:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  if(modalIsOpen) return; // this

  if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 65) {
    beforeAfterImages(1);
    gtfval();
  }

  if(e.which == 39 || e.which == 68) {
    beforeAfterImages(2);
    gtfval();
  }

})
```